# Not able to read strings from region specific folders in Android

Tags: android, localization, locale

I am trying to override locale configuration in my app. But, I am not able to differentiate between language and their regions.

I am trying following code to override the locale.

Getting locale to override.

Example : "de_DE", "de_AT"

```
public static Locale getLocaleFromString(@NonNull final String locale) {

        String[] split = locale.split("_");

        if (split != null || split.length > 1) {
            String language = split[0];
            String country = split[1];

            return new Locale(language, language, country);
        }

        return Locale.getDefault();
    }
```

The structure of my resource folders is:

```
values/strings.xml    (default strings)
values-de-rDE/strings.xml
values-de-rAT/strings.xml
```

If, I define values-de/strings.xml, application start reading from this folder.
That means locale overriding works in app, but some how android system is not able to read string from region specific folders.

(My device language is english.)

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The arguments passed to Location's constructor may be wrong:
The second should be country and the third should be variant.

So `getLocaleFromString` should like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Resources res = getResources();
        DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
        Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
        conf.locale = getLocaleFromString("de_DE");
        res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public static Locale getLocaleFromString(@NonNull final String locale) {

        String[] split = locale.split("_");

        if (split != null || split.length > 1) {
            String language = split[0];
            String country = split[1];
            return new Locale(language, country);
        }

        return Locale.getDefault();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show me your code of changing language. I added the code of changing language.

Comment: Does, this code works for you? Because I tried this code and it has no effect in my app.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. I actually got my mistake. I was calling getLocaleFromString after setContentView.